# Wann ist »weniger …, sondern …« zulässig?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, conjunction

Laut [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Besonderheiten-von-sondern) drückt *sondern* bekanntlich einen Gegensatz aus. Dieser setze voraus, dass zuvor etwas verneint worden sei, beispielsweise durch *nicht* oder *kein*:

> Uns fehlen nicht nur Teller, sondern auch Gläser.
>
> Das ist kein Hamster, sondern ein Meerschweinchen.

Wenn die Verneinung nicht explizit vorliege, dürfe *sondern* allerdings nicht verwendet werden:

> Das war weniger schlau als vielmehr hinterlistig.

Nun komme sie aber doch noch, die Ausnahme. Stehe nämlich *kaum* im ersten Teil, dürfe der Anschluss dennoch mit *sondern* erfolgen:

> Er hat kaum gearbeitet, sondern nur vor sich hin geträumt.
> Wir hoffen, dies war nun weniger verwirrend als vielmehr erhellend.

Trotzdem sehe ich die Kombination *weniger …, sondern …* oft, inklusive auf den Seiten von Duden selbst, etwa bei:

> [Schöngeist](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schoengeist): jemand, der sich weniger mit alltäglichen Dingen beschäftigt, sondern in Belletristik, Kunst o. Ä. schwelgt, darin aufgeht
>
> [Gedankenlyrik](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gedankenlyrik): Lyrik, die bestimmte Gegenstände, besonders weltanschauliche Zusammenhänge u. Ä., weniger durch eine bildhafte Sprache, sondern in erster Linie durch die Entwicklung rationaler Gedankengänge bzw. argumentativ darstellt.

Wann darf man also *weniger X, sondern Y* im strengen Sinne schreiben und wann nicht?

Comment: Ich möchte wieder einmal darauf hinweisen, dass der Duden nicht *vor*schreibt, was man dürfe, sondern *be*schreibt, was (in einer ausreichend großen Zahl von Texten) getan wurde. Kurz: er ist nicht _normativ_, sondern _deskriptiv_.

Comment: Das scheint eine relativ neue Sprachentwicklung zu sein - Der Grimm hat eine extra Abteilung für "sondern ohne Negation". http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GS31290#XGS31290

Comment: Ich möchte nur mal anmerken, dass die exzessive Verwendung des Konjunktivs im OP das Textverständnis ziemlich erschwert. Konjunktiv I mag ja eine nette Sache sein, aber man muss es auch nicht übertreiben mit der Sprachpflege ;)

Comment: Ich stelle mal eine Variation des Gegenbeispiels in den Raum: "Jemand, der weniger mit alltäglichen Dingen beschäftigt ist, als mit dem Schwelgen in Belletristik, Kunst o. Ä. " --- hier funktioniert das 'weniger...als', im Gegensatz zum Original-Beispiel, wo es deplatziert wirken würde.

Comment: @user0 Es geht hier weder um Rechtschreibung noch um Grammatik, sondern pur um Semantik. Ich glaube, der Duden überschreitet hier seine Kompetenzen.

Answer (score 1):

Es lassen sich viele Beispiele finden, die der genannten Behauptung des Duden widersprechen:

> Ich gehe nicht ins Kino - weil ich krank bin - aber würde gerne

Mit der "zu einfachen" Erklärung des Duden müsste hier eigentlich "sondern" stehen - was keinen rechten Sinn ergeben will.

*sondern* sollte dann verwendet werden, wenn die Konzepte, die in den verbundenen Teilsätzen beschrieben werden, *sich gegenseitig ausschließen*. Und wenn das nicht der Fall ist - eben nicht. Im Kino-Beispiel oben schließt sich das "Nicht gehen" und "trotzdem wollen" eben nicht aus.

Genau dasselbe gilt auch für die "weniger/mehr"-Beispiele in der Frage - Dort schließen sich die durch "sondern" verbundenen Konzepte eben rein logisch erstmal nicht aus - Wenn man "sondern" verwendet, impliziert man damit, dass sie es doch tun. Das kann aber durchaus auch gewollt sein. Man würde damit ausdrücken, dass man zwar "weniger" sagt, aber eigentlich "nicht" meint.

Für mich ist eine Regel, die sagt, dass man bestimmte Wörter nur zu bestimmten Sachverhalten benutzen dürfe, ziemlich sinnlos. Sprache ist keine Mathematik, darf damit wesentlich uneindeutiger sein, und das, was man sagt, muss nicht notwendigerweise das sein, was man dem Wortsinn nach meint.

Um deine Frage aus dem Titel zu beantworten: "Weniger...sondern" ist immer dann "zulässig", wenn es ausdrückt, was du meinst.

Answer (score 0):

Duden ist nicht normativ; laut [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Konjunktion/Bedeutung/adversativ.html) und der ersten Grammatik, die mir in die Hände gefallen ist, ist *sondern* einfach eine adversative Konjunktion.

Wenn man das *nicht nur …, sondern auch...* einmal außen vorlässt - hier sind ja offensichtlich keine Gegensätze gemeint - sind die Beispiele alle von der Art, dass sie erklärt werden müssen. Wenn ich weniger von a habe, was habe ich dann mehr? Diese Art der Entgegensetzung beschränkt sich m. E. nicht auf das reine *Gegenteil*, auch wenn ich *als vielmehr* im Vergleich mit *sondern* als besser passend empfinde.

Comment: *Ich möchte wieder einmal darauf hinweisen, dass der Duden nicht vorschreibt, was man dürfe, sondern beschreibt, was (in einer ausreichend großen Zahl von Texten) getan wurde. Kurz: er ist nicht normativ, sondern deskriptiv.* Endlich ist es gesagt: das finde ich grossartig! Das ist ja hoch interessant zu hören! Und warum wurden dann meine Antworten immer kritisiert, sie seien anekdotisch und wenn schon müssten sie mit Duden etc. belegt werden. (Ich bin schliesslich auch nicht normativ, nur deskriptiv! - höchstens spekulativ.)